# Actionscript 3: Class constructor in function variable?

Tags: function, variables, actionscript, constructor

I want to make a variable hold a class constructor, but it gives this error:

```
var myFunction:Function
function someFunction() {}

myFunction = someFunction //works
myFunction = MovieClip    //doesn't work - 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Class to an unrelated type Function.
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

The correct type to hold a class is [`Class`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Class.html), not `Function`.

```
var myClass:Class = MovieClip;
```